# Notification service for ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arccatalog

I am dealing with long  and demanding analyses, which needs  often lots of data and time ( between few hours to couple of days) and it can happen a full stop/break on my workstations caused by diverse failures (data bugs, overflow, unexpected etc)

Is it possible to develop a  "Process Notification"  service, which can send an e-mail from ArcCatalog  to a chosen recipient about the actual status  , i.e.   Reporting  the status  in a brief form  : [1] Finished  [2] Break or Failure  [3] Estimated time left to be finished.

Our solution is not covering entirely the problem above .

For details: 
[ http://geomatika.mapcat.net/COMMON/Projects/process_notifier_v0.41.zip ]

Comment: Is your tool running inside ArcCatalog, or have you started a script or something external from ArcCatalog?

Comment: This is just a simple external (generic) solution. We thought it can be useful for monitoring and notification purposes in any similar cases.

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15532/150) you could use a Python [SMTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/logging.html#smtp-handler) to send emails based on log messages as necessary as the script executes.

Comment: Here is some code.  Your IT department may prohibit you from connecting to the SMTP server.https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/arcpy-sending-a-result-email/

Answer (score 1):

[Making ArcGIS for Desktop play sound on speaker when model completes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103393/making-arcgis-for-desktop-play-sound-on-speaker-when-model-completes)

Also includes instructions for emailing you on completion. I've used it, and it works...although it only fires on completion.